# GoRoute enter in initialLocation also for different path

Tags: flutter, gorouter, flutter-go-router

Hello i have a problem with go_router.
When I do a context.push to a other router declared in Router, it pass from initialLocation.

My initial location is "/home" the other route where i am going is "/new-product".

Why happen that?

```
   onPressed: () {
       context.push(RoutingPath.uploadProduct);
   },
```

```
class TwRouter extends GoRouter {
  TwRouter(
    final AuthenticationService auth,
    final TokenService tokenService,
    final NavigationService navigationService,
  ) : super(
          debugLogDiagnostics: true,
          redirect: (state) {
              ...
              return null;
          },
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: RoutingPath.home,
              builder: (context, state) => TwDefaultLayout(
                  authenticationService: auth,
                  tokenService: tokenService,
                  initialPage: navigationService.currentPage,
                  pageList: [
                    HomePage(reload: state.extra as bool?),
                  ],
                  listIcons: const [
                    "assets/images/icons/bottom_bar/home.svg",
                  ]),
            ),
            GoRoute(
                path: RoutingPath.uploadProduct,
                builder: (context, state) => UploadProduct(
                authenticationService: auth,
                tokenService: tokenService,
            ),
        ),
          ],
          refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(auth.authStateChanges.stream
            ..forEach((element) => debugPrint(element.toString()))),
          initialLocation: RoutingPath.home,
   );
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I update my request